# La base de datos no se ejecuta

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estoy ejecutando una base de datos ya creada en otra clase, pero no sé porque no se ejecuta:
En este código:

```
DB baseHelper = new DB(this, "DEMODB", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if(db != null){
        ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
        registronuevo.put("Nombre", strNombre);
        registronuevo.put("Preg5", strPregCinco);
        registronuevo.put("Preg4", strPregCuatro);
        long i = db.insert("Datos", null, registronuevo);
        if (gruporadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") || strPregCuatro.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡Dejaste campos vacíos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (i>0){
            Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(pas);
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡Encuesta enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hubo un error, intenta más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

No se ejecuta la base de datos, porque cuando estoy en la app, se ejecuta la sentencia

```
else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hubo un error, intenta más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

y no la sentencia que se ejecuta cuando la base de datos se ejecuta

```
else if (i>0){
        Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(pas);
        Toast.makeText(context, "¡Encuesta enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

, lo cual significa que no se está ejecutando la base de datos.

Aquí esta la base de datos creada en otra clase llamada `DB.java`

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String tabla = ("CREATE TABLE Datos(nombre text)");

    public DB(Context context, String nombre, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(tabla);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNva) {
        //Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Datos");

        //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
        db.execSQL(tabla);
    }
}
```

Comment: No necesitas los parentesis al definir el String tabla, debe ser :  String tabla = "CREATE TABLE Datos (nombre text)"; , además es importante el uso del LogCat en Android, esto para encontrar fácilmente los problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error tipográfico estas tratando de crear una tabla llamada "Datos(nombre" , además no necesitas `(` y `)` ya que estas declarando una cadena.

```
String tabla = ("CREATE TABLE Datos(nombre text)");
```

corrige el script de esta forma:

```
String tabla = "CREATE TABLE Datos (nombre text)";
```

#### Actualización:

Script final: `String tabla = "CREATE TABLE Datos (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, N text, C text, R1 INTEGER, R2 INTEGER, R3 INTEGER, P4 text, P5 text)";`

Se reviso con el usuario y el script funcionó correctamente solo que no creaba una nueva estructura de la tabla, para esto la solución es:

- Eliminar la aplicación y volver a instalarla para crear la estructura correcta.
- Eliminar el caché de la aplicación, al iniciar creará la estructura correcta.

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a corregir esa linea y en seguida te aviso si me funciona.

Comment: hecho! saludos.

Comment: Otra pregunta, donde dices que uso (y)?

Comment: String tabla = ("CREATE TABLE Datos(nombre text)"); debe ser : String tabla = "CREATE TABLE Datos (nombre text)";

Comment: No funciono :( el error no sale en el LogCat, lo que pasa es que, puse un else que imprima "Hubo un error, intenta mas tarde" para saber si no funciono y ninguna condicion se ejecuto. Entonces el error es que se ejecuta ese else :(

Comment: Vale, igual ya te lo paso, sigamos esto en un chat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55030/discussion-between-pablo-gonzalez-and-jorgesys).

Comment: @PabloGonzalez Pablo esto funcionó es así?

Comment: Sip, funciono gracias a ti Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

El `insert` no puede funcionar. Cuando creas la tabla, lo creas con una sola columna, tipo `TEXT`, llamado "nombre":

```
String tabla = ("CREATE TABLE Datos(nombre text)");
```

Cuando tratas de insertar una fila, pasas tres columnas, "nombre", "preg5" y "preg4".

Tu `CREATE` entonces debería ser algo como:

```
String tabla = ("CREATE TABLE Datos(nombre TEXT, preg4 TEXT, preg5 TEXT)");
```

Comment: Hola, ya cambie esa linea, pero aun asi no se ejecuta la condicion que yo quiero. No entiendo que esta pasando.